# UNDEFINED response in getting the return multiple values from PHP to AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get the return multiple value from my php to ajax, but the problem is I always get a Undefined response from my page. I tried different ways but still getting the same problem

here is my code...

addSizeandPrice.php

```
if($selectResult){
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectResult)){
        $dataprice = $data['Price'];
        $datasize = $data['CoffeeSize'];

        echo json_encode (array(
            'size' => $datasize,
            'price' => $dataprice,
        ));
    }
}
```

billingCoffee.php

```
$.ajax({
    url: "addSizeandPrice.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {coffeename: txtCoffeeName, sizes: cmbSizes, price: txtPrice},
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (result){
        alert(result.size);
        alert(result.price);
    }
});
```

Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. . :)

Comment: What does that javascript code do in a php file?

Comment: What result do you get? ?

Comment: it will always show an alert box with a word UNDEFINED...

Answer (score 0):

Your json_encode is incorrect. If your DB query returns MULTIPLE rows, then you're sending out MULTIPLE separate json-encoded strings, which is a syntax error. e.g.

```
{"size":"val1","price":"val1"}{"size":"val2","price":"val2"}
                             ^^--illegal/invalid javascript
```

You should have:

```
$arr = array();
while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectResult)){
    $dataprice = $data['Price'];
    $datasize = $data['CoffeeSize'];
    $arr[] = array(
        'size' => $datasize,
        'price' => $dataprice,
    )
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

which would produce:

```
[{"size":"val1","price":"val1"},{"size":"val2","price":"val2"}]
```

which is valid javascript/json, and then

```
success: function(response) { console.log(response[0].size); }
```